# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null

Tags: java

I am working on a web application that accepts json data from third parties, processes that data and responds to them with processed json data.

I am getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null on production server which I am unable to reproduce on my local machine. Below is the stack trace:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:246)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:227)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.readSocket(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:422)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:794)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:819)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:124)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:346)
at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:290)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:449)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:315)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:200)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:205)
at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:279)
at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
```

The piece of code that throws this exception (particularly 'while' condition):

```
public static String getPostData(HttpServletRequest request) throws 
IOException {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } else {
            stringBuilder.append("");
        }
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            bufferedReader.close();
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

This application is deployed in 3 different AWS regions with the same server config and surprisingly only one of the regions throws this exception and that too only for a very few random requests.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to manually test the connection with `curl` from the problematic production server?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni : Yes , I did test with curl command. It works. Unfortunately it fails for few random requests, not all of them.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

In order to reproduce a socket timeout exception, you have to make your client start a download and then pause downloading for a while. You could achieve this by

- installing a OS tool which can emulate different networking situations (bandwidth, latency, etc.)
- writing your own test client (see https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/sockettimeoutexception/java-net-sockettimeoutexception-how-to-solve-sockettimeoutexception/)